# Do I need transit visa?

Tags: visas, transit, lhr

I am trying to book a ticket for my sister to come visit me in Canada. She is Belarussian (belarua) but has a visitor visa for Canada. On way back to Belarus she is flying Halifax to London and then London to Vienna and then Vienna to Minsk. My concern does she need a transit visa in London if she staying at the airport for 6 hours till her next flight?

Comment: my concern is  with London airport!

Comment: Check this site: https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa.  With a valid visa for Canada, she should be able to transit the UK without a UK visa, even if she has to pass through border control.